# Serializing many to many relationship with attributes does not show attribute in the relationship

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

My conceptual model is that there are `DemanderFeature` objects which have `LoadCurve` objects linked to them in a many-to-many relationship, along with a single attribute indicating "how many times" the two are associated, using an attribute in the many-to-many relationship called `number`.

I have been struggling for quite a while now, reading many answers on stackoverflow but I just cannot get it to work in exactly the way that I want. This is my desired output, when looking at the detail view of a `DemanderFeature`:

```
HTTP 200 OK
Allow: GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept

[
    {
        "name": "testdemander",
        "loadcurves": [
            {"name": "lc", "number": 5},
            {"name": "lc2", "number": 10}
        ],
        // Other DemanderFeature fields removed for brevity...
    }
]
```

The closest I have been able to get to this is with this setup:

## Models

```
class LoadCurve(models.Model):

    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    finalized = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    owner = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    length = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    deleted = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    demanderfeatures = models.ManyToManyField("DemanderFeature", through="DemanderFeatureToLoadCurveAssociation")

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['name']
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(fields=["owner", "name"], condition=models.Q(deleted=False), name="loadcurve_unique_owner_name")
        ]

class DemanderFeature(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    owner = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    demanderfeaturecollection = models.ForeignKey(DemanderFeatureCollection, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    loadcurves = models.ManyToManyField("LoadCurve", through="DemanderFeatureToLoadCurveAssociation")
    deleted = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    geom = gis_models.PointField(default=None)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['name']
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(fields=["owner", "demanderfeaturecollection", "name"], condition=models.Q(deleted=False),
                                    name="demanderfeature_unique_owner_demanderfeaturecollection_name")
        ]

class DemanderFeatureToLoadCurveAssociation(models.Model):

    loadcurve = models.ForeignKey(LoadCurve, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    demanderfeature = models.ForeignKey(DemanderFeature, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    number = models.IntegerField()
```

## Serializers

(I am using `__all__` for the sake of debugging, so that I can see everything that is being serialized and available)

```
class LoadCurveSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = LoadCurve
        fields = "__all__"


class DemanderFeatureToLoadCurveAssociationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = DemanderFeatureToLoadCurveAssociation
        fields = "__all__"


class DemanderFeatureSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    demanderfeaturecollection = serializers.SlugRelatedField(slug_field="name", queryset=DemanderFeatureCollection.objects.all())
    loadcurves = LoadCurveSerializer(read_only=True, many=True)
    # loadcurves = DemanderFeatureToLoadCurveAssociationSerializer(read_only=True, many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = DemanderFeature
        fields = "__all__"
        lookup_field = "name"
```

There is a commented line in the previous code block which I was trying to use to get the `DemanderFeatureToLoadCurveAssociationSerializer` because I thought this would be the proper way to get the `number` field which its related model defines, but when I uncomment this line (and comment the line just below it) I only get this error:

```
AttributeError at /demanderfeatures/

Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `number` on serializer `DemanderFeatureToLoadCurveAssociationSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `LoadCurve` instance.
Original exception text was: 'LoadCurve' object has no attribute 'number'.
```

If I do not swap those lines, however, I get this as a result:

```
HTTP 200 OK
Allow: GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept

[
    {
        "name": "testdemander",
        "loadcurves": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "created": "2020-12-29T11:29:11.585034Z",
                "finalized": true,
                "name": "lc",
                "length": 0,
                "deleted": false,
                "owner": 1,
                "demanderfeatures": [
                    1
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "created": "2020-12-29T12:46:31.044624Z",
                "finalized": true,
                "name": "lc2",
                "length": 0,
                "deleted": false,
                "owner": 1,
                "demanderfeatures": [
                    1
                ]
            }
        ],
        // Other DemanderFeature fields removed for brevity...
    }
]
```

Which does not contain that critical `number` field which is defined in the `DemanderFeatureToLoadCurveAssociation` model.

I feel like I am just missing something quite obvious but I have not been able to find it.

Comment: I have created a Q&A which answers the same situation, you can refer this, [Serialize ManyToManyFields with a Through Model in Django REST Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65493883/drf-manytomanyfields-with-a-through-model)

Comment: Thanks, @JPG. I was finally able to get it "working" with a custom serializer but the implementation felt hacky and weird, but it looks like what you did is somewhat similar, I assume just in a more proper and streamlined way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm putting my specific implementation here in case it is useful to anyone. It is adapted from @JPG's own [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65493883/serialize-manytomanyfields-with-a-through-model-in-django-rest-framework) which was made as a response to this question (probably because it would be a pain to try to re-create my entire ORM and environment). I adapted their code to my own implementation.

It is worth noting however that this implementation only works one way. I originally tried implementing it with such a conceptual mapping:

- `DemanderFeature` -> `Person`
- `LoadCurve` -> `Group`
- `Membership` -> `DemanderFeatureToLoadCurveAssociation`

But since I wanted to see all the associated `LoadCurve` objects when retrieving a `DemanderFeature` object, I actually needed to flip this mapping around so that `DemanderFeature` objects are equivalent to `Group` objects and `LoadCurve` objects are equivalent to `Person` objects. It is obvious to me now why this is (I am conceptualizing the `DemanderFeature` as a GROUP of `LoadCurves`), but at the time I didn't see the technical difference.

Anyway here is the updated serializers.py. Thanks again @JPG for taking the time!

```
class LoadCurveSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = LoadCurve
        fields = ["name"]

    def serialize_demanderfeaturetoloadcurveassociation(self, loadcurve_instance):
        # simple method to serialize the through model fields
        demanderfeaturetoloadcurveassociation_instance = loadcurve_instance \
            .demanderfeaturetoloadcurveassociation_set \
            .filter(demanderfeature=self.context["demanderfeature_instance"]) \
            .first()

        if demanderfeaturetoloadcurveassociation_instance:
            return DemanderFeatureToLoadCurveAssociationSerializer(demanderfeaturetoloadcurveassociation_instance).data
        return {}

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        rep = super().to_representation(instance)
        return {**rep, **self.serialize_demanderfeaturetoloadcurveassociation(instance)}


class DemanderFeatureToLoadCurveAssociationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer): # create new serializer to serialize the through model fields
    class Meta:
        model = DemanderFeatureToLoadCurveAssociation
        fields = ["number"]


class DemanderFeatureSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    demanderfeaturecollection = serializers.SlugRelatedField(slug_field="name", queryset=DemanderFeatureCollection.objects.all())
    loadcurves = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = DemanderFeature
        fields = ["name", "demanderfeaturecollection", "loadcurves", "geom"]
        # fields = "__all__"
        lookup_field = "name"

    def get_loadcurves(self, demanderfeature):
        return LoadCurveSerializer(
            demanderfeature.loadcurve_set.all(),
            many=True,
            context={"demanderfeature_instance": demanderfeature}  # should pass this `group` instance as context variable for filtering
        ).data
```