# Serialize ManyToManyFields with a Through Model in Django REST Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have this M2M relation with `through` model as

```py
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    members = models.ManyToManyField(Person, through='Membership')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Membership(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_joined = models.DateField()
    invite_reason = models.CharField(max_length=64)
```

Please note that, I have extra fields **`date_joined`** and **`invite_reason`** in the through model.

Now, I want to serialize the **`Group`** queryset using DRF and thus I choose the below serializer setup.

```py
class PersonSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = "__all__"


class GroupSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    members = PersonSerializer(read_only=True, many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Group
        fields = "__all__"
```

and it is returning the following response,

```json
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "members": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Jerin"
            }
        ],
        "name": "Developer"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "members": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Jerin"
            }
        ],
        "name": "Team Lead"
    }
]
```

Here, the **`members`** field returning the `Person` information, which is perfect.

But,

**How can I add the `date_joined` and `invite_reason` field/info into the `members` field of the JSON response?**

Answer (score 1):

```
class PersonSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = "__all__"

    def serialize_membership(self, person_instance):
        # simple method to serialize the through model fields
        membership_instance = person_instance \
            .membership_set \
            .filter(group=self.context["group_instance"]) \
            .first()

        if membership_instance:
            return MembershipSerializer(membership_instance).data
        return {}

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        rep = super().to_representation(instance)
        return {**rep, **self.serialize_membership(instance)}


class MembershipSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer): # create new serializer to serialize the through model fields
    class Meta:
        model = Membership
        fields = ("date_joined", "invite_reason")


class GroupSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    members = serializers.SerializerMethodField() # use `SerializerMethodField`, can be used to pass context data 

    def get_members(self, group):
        return PersonSerializer(
            group.members.all(),
            many=True,
            context={"group_instance": group}  # should pass this `group` instance as context variable for filtering
        ).data

    class Meta:
        model = Group
        fields = "__all__"
```

Notes:

- Override the **`to_representation(...)`** method of `PersonSerializer` to *inject* extra data into the `members` field of the JSON
- We need `person` instance/pk and `group` instance/pk to identify the `Membership` instance to be serialized. For that, we have used the *serializer context* to pass essential data

Comment: Thanks for the very detailed answer but I cannot get my implementation to recognize that the appropriate keyword exists in `self.context`. I am trying to adapt this code to my implementation. It fails on this line: `.filter(group=self.context["group_instance"]) \` (but using my terminology. I have updated my original question which prompted this Q&A to show how I tried to adapt this code and maybe you can see where I went wrong, but I've tried to go over it several times and have not found a significant difference.

Comment: The reason it wasn't working was because I had the conceptual mapping backwards. What should have been my `Group` objects were actually my `Person` objects and vice versa. Reversing the mapping fixed it.

Comment: This worked for me. Doing things with `ReadOnlyField(source="...")` to include fields from the relation,... as I could read in other answers didn't. Thank for this answer.

Comment: in my case, the code also fails on `.filter(group=self.context["group_instance"]) `. Models and serializers are the same as JPG's; perhaps the issue is with how my views are defined (the context is not passed to the serializer correctly)? 

```
from rest_framework import viewsets

class PersonViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Person.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PersonSerializer
```